# how to set time out for sql query transaction in java application

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

how to set time out for sql query transaction in java application which uses SpringJDBC or Hibernate.
Say in banking application we need to execute query in stipulated time (3 secs)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
template.setQueryTimeout(3);
```